# How could I read one to many linked table using link with Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, frameworks, entity

I am new to Entity Framework and Linq (Visual Studio 2017 - EF 5.0) . Currently, I could read tables without issue but wonder how could I read a linked table.
My current functions do it but sure there is a simple way than two step reading that I have developed.

```
public override List<CartItem> GetMyCartOrderItems(int UserID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (foodorderingdbEntities oMConnection = new foodorderingdbEntities())
            {

                var oCart = oMConnection.carts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.USER_ID == UserID);
                if (oCartItems != null)
                {
                    int CartID = oCart.CART_ID;
                    var oCartItems = oMConnection.cart_item.Where(p => p.CART_ITEM_CART_ID == CartID);
                    if (oCartItems != null)
                    {
                        List<CartItem> oRecList = new List<CartItem>();
                        foreach (cart_item oDBrec in oCartItems)
                        {
                            CartItem oRec = new CartItem();
                            oRec.CartID = oDBrec.CART_ITEM_ID;
                            oRec.CartItemID = oDBrec.CART_ITEM_CART_ID;
                            oRec.DateTime = oDBrec.CART_ITEM_ADDED_DATE_TIME;
                            oRec.SystemComments = oDBrec.CART_ITEM_SYSTEM_COMMENTS;
                            oRecList.Add(oRec);
                        }
                        return oRecList;
                    } 
                else { return null; }
                }
                else { return null; }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //IBLogger.Write(LOG_OPTION.ERROR, "File : MHCMySQLDataConection.cs, Method : GetPatientByID(1), Exception Occured :" + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Trace :" + ex.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

You could see that I get Cart ID from Carts table using UserID and then I use the CartID retrieve cart Items from Cart_Item table. Cart_Item_Cart_ID is a foreign key in cart_item table. (This is a one to many table)

This is what I am thinking but obviously does not work.

`List<cart_item> oCartItems = oMConnection.carts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.USER_ID == UserID).cart_item.Where(p => p.CART_ITEM_CART_ID = c.CART_ID).ToList<cart_item>();`

Any help ?

My entity relation[image]

```
public partial class cart
{
    public cart()
    {
        this.cart_item = new HashSet<cart_item>();
    }

    public int CART_ID { get; set; }
    public int USER_ID { get; set; }
    public decimal ORDER_TOTAL_COST { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<cart_item> cart_item { get; set; }
    public virtual user user { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does your cart have a navigation property to items?  It should, and if so, then just `var oCart = db.carts.Include(x=>x.Items).Where(...);` (make sure you have `using System.Data.Entity;` for the lambda extension Include)

Comment: I have foreign key setup in cart_item table.  Could you please complete the above query so that I could understand what you are trying to do? The issue is that I need to query the second table using a key from first table.

Comment: The complete query would be `var oCart = oMConnection.carts.Include(x=>x.Items).Where(c=>c.USER_ID == UserID);` is that what you mean?  Can you post your Cart class, that would indicate if you have the navigation properties set up correctly.  This article might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I added the class for cart and entity relation model

Comment: In the above statement, you pull the record from cart table where UserID is matched. That's not what I am trying to do.  I added the entity relation model and it's clear I guess. I need to get the list from cart_item table where its cart ID is matched to cart table from User ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your query has multiple levels of one to many relationships, and you just want the cart_items, it's easier to go the other way like this:

```
var oCart = oMConnection.cart_item
  .Where(c=>c.cart.user.USER_ID == UserID);
```

Going the way you did should have worked as well, but you needed to use SelectMany instead of select like this:

```
var oCartItems = oMConnection.carts
  .Where(c=>c.USER_ID==UserID)
  .SelectMany(c=>c.cart_item);
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much.